# What exactly `git diff` shows after resolving merge conflict? and how to see only the new changes?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I merge branch A to branch B:

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

a conflict happens, in a file `c.txt`. I resolve it by editing `c.txt` file. Now, before approving the changes with `git add c.txt` I would like to see them. I.e. to **see the difference between  `c.txt` and branch A. How to do it?**

If I simply use `git diff c.txt` it shows much more than the changes I want. It seems to show both, changes from branch B and changes from branch A (comparing to their common original commit). I.e. result is different from `git add c.txt; git diff --cached c.txt`.
**What exactly does `git diff c.txt` shows me when `c.txt` is marked as in conflict?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: you probably want `git diff HEAD:c.txt c.txt`.

---

While the file is marked "conflicted", there are multiple "higher stage" entries for the file in Git's index.  In fact, this is what it means for the file to *be* conflicted in the first place: a non-conflicted file is in "stage zero" in Git's index, and a conflicted file has stage 1, 2, and/or 3 entries (typically all three).

When the file is in this conflicted state, `git diff` performs a *combined diff* on the file.

Using `git add` on the file erases the higher-stage entries, leaving you with a single stage-zero (non-conflicted) file, which is why it stops showing up that way.

> Now, before approving the changes with git add c.txt I would like to see them. I.e. to **see the difference between c.txt and branch A.** How to do it?

I don't normally bother with this (I just read the combined diff, or `git add` the file and then can see what I want without anything fancier—remember, you can still access the other versions of the file; only the *merge base* version is hard-ish to find), but you *can* do this.  You must pick out which two copies of `c.txt` you want compared:

- One of those is, you say, the copy in some commit (`branch A`): that's `A:c.txt`.
- The other copy is up to you: there's one in the `HEAD` commit, one in the `MERGE_HEAD` commit, three in Git's index, and one in your working tree.  The tricky part is naming each of these, but we can use [the gitrevisions syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for most of this.  As with `A:c.txt`, `HEAD:c.txt` and `MERGE_HEAD:c.txt` work for selecting those versions; `:1:c.txt` selects the merge base version; `:2:c.txt` selects the `--ours` version (copied from `HEAD` so should match `HEAD:c.txt`), and `:3:c.txt` selects the `--theirs` version (copied from `MERGE_HEAD`).

Thus, if you wanted, e.g., to see how `HEAD:c.txt` differs from `MERGE_HEAD:c.txt`, you can just run `git diff HEAD:c.txt MERGE_HEAD:c.txt` (or `git diff :2:c.txt :3:c.txt`).

That doesn't help with the one you probably care about the most, though.  What about the copy of `c.txt` in your working tree, as edited to produce the combined file?  Fortunately, we can name that one with just the file name, `c.txt`.

In some cases, this file name *might resemble a branch name*, tricking Git.  If that's the case, make sure you remember that `--` always tells Git: *after this, everything is a file name, or at least, not an option and probably not a branch name*.  So if the file isn't named `c.txt` but rather `main`, and:

```
git diff HEAD:main main
```

does the wrong thing, use:

```
git diff HEAD:main -- main
```

(note that `HEAD:main` isn't going to be mistaken for a branch name and the `--` should go between these).

#### Note on order reversal problems

If you wanted to compare the in-tree `c.txt` to the branch-A `c.txt`, both:

```
git diff c.txt A:c.txt
```

and:

```
git diff A:c.txt c.txt
```

work.  The order of the two arguments determines which file is the "before" or left-side one, and which one is the "after" or right-side one, which in turn determines which lines are deleted and which lines are added.

In most cases, if the diff you asked for is "backwards" from the order you *meant*, you can simply swap the arguments.  But for:

```
git diff HEAD:main -- main
```

there is a problem: you can't swap these.  Here, `git diff -R` comes to the rescue: the `-R` flag means *swap the sides*.  So `git diff -R HEAD:main -- main` does the trick: the `main` file winds up on the left, and the `HEAD:main` file winds up on the right.